# why does opencv convert color space different from pil?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert an normal image to gray and hsv color-space with opencv and PIL, however, I found the results are not same:

```
## convert to gray
im_pil = np.array(Image.open(imgpth).convert("L"))
im_cv = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(imgpth), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(np.sum(im_pil - im_cv))

## convert to hsv
im_pil = np.array(Image.open(imgpth).convert("HSV").split()[0])
im_cv = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(imgpth), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:, :, 0]
print(np.sum(im_pil - im_cv))
```

Where does the difference come from? Can I make the two results same?

Comment: By default, OpenCV uses BGR format while PIL uses RGB. They are simply represented differently

Comment: That is the reason I used cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY rather than cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY

Comment: HSL, channel L is not the same as converting to gray. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV. HSV channel 0 would be Hue not Value and not commensurate with converting to gray. Value and Gray are not the same. See the same reference for HSV definition. Gray is often the same as Luma (Y), from YIQ, YCbCr, and YUV. But sometimes it is just RGB desaturated. V is max(R,G,B). L is 0.5*(max(R,G,B)-min(R,G,B)). Gray is a weighted average of R,G,B.

Comment: Thanks, would you write an answer and show me how I could change the opencv part to make the two results to be 0s?

Comment: Both, [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) and [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html) claim to use ITU-R 601-2 luma transform, i.e. `L = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B`. If I try to implement that simple calculation by myself, I get deviations against Pillow and OpenCV! It seems, OpenCV is close to `np.round(...calculation...)`, and Pillow is close to `np.uint8(...calculation...)`. Deep dive into both source codes to see what they're actually doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @HansHirse suggests in the comments, the difference in greyscale conversion  between OpenCV and PIL is that OpenCV uses nearest integer rounding (`nint()`) whereas PIL uses rounding down (`int()`).

The following program demonstrates that by generating 1x1 pixel images of pure red from 0..255, then pure green from 0..255 and then pure blue from 0..255 and converting them with both OpenCV and PIL.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

print("Varying red through 0..255, showing red component, OpenCV grey, PIL grey")
for r in range(256):
    ocvim = np.zeros((1,1,3), dtype=np.uint8) 
    ocvim[0,0,0] = r
    ocvgrey = cv2.cvtColor(ocvim,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    pilim = Image.new('RGB',(1,1),(r,0,0)).convert('L')
    print(r,ocvgrey[0,0],pilim.getpixel((0,0)))

print("Varying green through 0..255, showing green component, OpenCV grey, PIL grey")
for g in range(256):
    ocvim = np.zeros((1,1,3), dtype=np.uint8) 
    ocvim[0,0,1] = g
    ocvgrey = cv2.cvtColor(ocvim,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    pilim = Image.new('RGB',(1,1),(0,g,0)).convert('L')
    print(g,ocvgrey[0,0],pilim.getpixel((0,0)))

print("Varying blue through 0..255, showing blue component, OpenCV grey, PIL grey")
for b in range(256):
    ocvim = np.zeros((1,1,3), dtype=np.uint8) 
    ocvim[0,0,2] = b
    ocvgrey = cv2.cvtColor(ocvim,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    pilim = Image.new('RGB',(1,1),(0,0,b)).convert('L')
    print(b,ocvgrey[0,0],pilim.getpixel((0,0)))
```

If you want to make **OpenCV** come to the same result as **PIL**, the easiest way is probably to let **OpenCV** do the calculation on a float value (rather than a `np.uint8`) to get the extra precision, then round it down yourself the same way as **PIL** does. So, instead of:

```
grey = cv2.cvtColor(uint8im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

you would use:

```
grey = cv2.cvtColor(uint8im.astype(np.float32),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).astype(np.uint8)
```

If you change the formulae in the code at the start of my answer to this format, the greyscale values calculated by **OpenCV** match those of **PIL**.